# Python quiz not performing multiple iteration?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, iteration

Below is my code. It is currently part of a program which is about a basic school quiz. My problem is that when I try to run the program, no errors appear but it only provides the user with one question. Could someone please explain to me why this is. Any help is much appreciated.

```
import random, math, sys, re, sqlite3, os
import operator as op

def inputName():
    username=str(input("What is your name?"))
if not re.match("^[A-Za-z ]*$", username) or username=="":
        username=input(str("Please enter a valid name (it must not contain numbers or symbols)."))
        print("Hi {}! Wellcome to the Arithmetic quiz...".format(username))
        username = None
        inputName()
    else:
        return username

def test():
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, num1)

    ops = {
        '+': op.add,
        '-': op.sub,
        '*': op.mul,
        }

    keys = list(ops.keys())
    rand_key = random.choice(keys)
    operation = ops[rand_key]

    correct_result = operation(num1, num2)

    print ("What is {} {} {}?".format(num1, rand_key, num2))
    while True:
            try:
                user_answer = int(input("Your answer: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Only enter numbers!")
            continue
        else:
            break

    if user_answer != correct_result:
        print ("Incorrect. The right answer is {}".format(correct_result))
       return False
    else:
       print("Correct!")
       return True

    correct_answers = 0
    num_questions = 10

    for i in range(num_questions):
       if test():
            correct_answers +=1

    print("{}: You got {}/{} correct.".format(username, correct_answers,  num_questions))
    return correct_answers

def makeDB():
    if os.path.exists("the_quiz_scores.db.db") == False: #checks if file doesn't exists
        makeFile = open("the_quiz_scores.db.db", "w") #if not, then it will create one
        makeFile.close()
    else:
        return True 

def mainProgram():

    name = inputName()
    maths = test()

mainProgram()
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: I keep coming across tab errors when I move my code. @IanAuld

Comment: You need to fix your indentation because your problem could very well be caused by bad indentation so I can't edit your question for you. Click the `edit` link under the tags to edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a `return` statement before you ever get here, specifically on lines 42 and 45:

```
for i in range(num_questions):
       print(range(num_questions))
       if test():
            correct_answers +=1
```

I suggest moving this loop outside of the `test()` function or moving it into it's own function. Once you hit those returns you exit the function and any code below them will never get executed.

Something like:

```
def loop_test(num_questions, username)
    correct_answers = 0
    for _ in range(num_questions):  # it's convention to use _ in a loop where you don't care about the value of the iterator
       if test():
            correct_answers += 1
    print("{}: You got {}/{} correct.".format(username, correct_answers,  num_questions))
    return correct_answers
```

Comment: Many thanks, being new to python when i go to call the function am I suppose to call the function with its parameters or am it leave it with out them. when it is run in the idle it suggests that the it be included and then when i do as told it is said to be undefined. @IanAuld

Comment: You must include any parameters that don't look like this in the function definition `def foo(a=None, b=5)`. Those are default parameters and unless a new value is supplied the indicated value will be used. The other exception is the `self` parameter of class methods. Read more about parameters [here](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/functions.html#function-parameters)

Comment: i cant seem to get my head round this. I'm not sure how i am meant to use the parameters in this instance @IanAuld

Comment: For example if you wanted 10 questions and your users name was stored in a variable `name` you call the function like so: `loop_test(10, name)`. The function would then substitute those values into the function in the appropriate place. A very simple example is `def foo(name): print(name)`. Try running that function with a few different parameters.